# Open and read latest json file one time only

Tags: python, json, file, glob

SO members...how can i read latest json file in a directory one time only (if no new file print something). So far I can only read the latest file ...The sample script (run every 45mins) below open and read latest json file in a directory. In this case latest file is file3.json (json file created every 30mins). Thus, if file4 is not created for some reason (for example server fail to create new json file). If the script run again.. it will still read the same last file3.

files in directory

```
file1.json
file2.json
file3.json
```

The script below able to open and read latest json file created in the directory.

```
import glob
import os
import os.path
import datetime, time

listFiles = glob.iglob('logFile/*.json') 
latestFile = max(listFiles, key=os.path.getctime)
with open(latestFile, 'r') as f:
   mydata = json.load(f)
   print(mydata)
```

To ensure the script will only read newest file and read the newest file one time only...aspect something below:-

```
listFiles = glob.iglob('logFile/*.json') 
latestFile = max(listFiles, key=os.path.getctime)
if latestFile newer than previous open/read file: # Not sure to compare the latest file with the previous file.
    with open(latestFile, 'r') as f:
       mydata = json.load(f)
       print(mydata)
else:
    print("no new file created")
```

Thank you for your help. Example solution would be good to share.

---

I can't figure out the solution...seems simple but few days try n error without any luck.

```
(1)Make sure read latest file in directory 
(2)Make sure read file/s that may miss to read (due to script fail to run)
(3)Only read once all the files and if no new file give warning.
```

Thank you.

---

After SO discussion and suggestion, I got few methods to resolve or at least to accommodate some of the requirement. I just move files that have been processed. If no file create, script will run nothing and if script fail and once normalize it will run and read all related files available. I think its good for now. Thank you guyz...

Comment: Will this be a continuously running script? If not you can use `pickle` to store the filename last read and compare with that on new file. In any case you have to store the context of last file somewhere. And what happens if last file you read was `file3` but before script runs again, there is a `file4` and a `file5` too?

Comment: Hi...the script will run every 45mins and get the latest json file. I forgot to tell that json files is created every 30mins. Thus, there should be new file for every 30mins. I foreseen issue if new json file fail to create and if script fail to run .. If script stop run...and few json files created (for example file4 and file5) .. script need to check again which file are miss and try to read those files...or or new json files not created as specified above.... i just not sure how to overcome the possibility issues.

Comment: If you are able to create a temporary cache file (i.e. a json file along side your script) then I believe all you could do is use that cache file to keep track of the `last file processed`, the `total items in the directory, during that last process` and maybe `timestamp of last process` (this one to help evaluate using date/time values of what next file to process)

Comment: Another approach might be to save the filenames as date and timestamp. 20200501103000 == 2020-05-01 10:30:00. Then if you os.listdir(), it’ll come out in order, and even if it don’t, you can just sort the list (cuz everything will be same length, even as strings it will sort correctly).

Comment: Also, what happens if you use os.stat()?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions... Im thinking to rename each 'latestFile' ... based on timestamp (created)..but than how to compare rename latestFile with actual new latestFile... I can see the logic but not able to translate it onto code...

Comment: If you are able to keep a log file, keep a log of some specific about the last file processed. 'Something specific' might be the time stamp, a check sum, etc. Then get the latest file and check that 'something specific' to see if you have already seen it.

Comment: I can get create time of latest file (os.path.getmtime(latestFile)) , float type... when i want to compare with somethg ..--> os.path.getmtime(latestFile) > maybe oldFile ... in this ...not sure how to get create time of oldFile...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the answer rather an approach, I would like to propose:

[image]

The idea is as follows:
Every log file that is written to a directory can have a key-val in it called `"creation_time": timestamp` (fileX.json that gets stored in the server). Now, your script runs at `45min` to obtain the file which is dumped to a directory. In normal cases, you must be able to read the file, and finally, when you exit the script you can store the last read filename and the creation_time taken from the `fileX.json` into a `logger.json`.
An example for a logger.json is as follows:

```
{
"creation_time": "03520201330",
"file_name": "file3.json"
}
```

Whenever a server fail or any delay occurs, there could be a rewritten of the `fileX.json` or `new fileX's.json` would have been created in the directory. In these situations, you would first open the logger.json and obtain both the timestamp and last filename as shown in the example above. By using the last filename, you can compare the old timestamp that is present in logger with the new timestamp in `fileX.json`. If they match basically there is no change you only read ahead files and rewrite the logger.
If that is not the case you would re-read the last `fileX.json` again and proceed to read other ahead files.

Comment: Hi coldy...this is good approach..i can understand the logic and it does includes all the requirement. Do you have any sample code similar that I can refer to...sorry not a coder and most of my time try n error...learn it.... anyway...thank you for your time and help...i appreciate it. thank you

Comment: I do not have a source code as such, I just design an approach with a little google of each of the steps I think it must be possible.

Comment: Thank you coldy. yaa... i have search around and still looking similar...

Comment: @chenoi You could accept the answer if it has helped you